# How to upload files using several file input types?

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl

I need to upload several files using several file input types. I know this can be done with just one input type with CTRL+click the files. I'm using perl as my back end part.

```
   <form action="dsadsa" method="post" enctype="multipart">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" multiple >
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" multiple>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" multiple>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" multiple>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" multiple>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <input type="submit" />
   </form>
```

That is my HTML part.

And im using ajaxForm plugin to upload the files.

```
var options = {
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            uploadProgress : function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {

            },
            success : function (data) {

            },
            error : function (response) {

            },
        };
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
```

But It cant get any parameters ( file_upload )

Just in case you want to see my perl side:

```
if ($path eq 'dsadas') {   #this is the path in the action part in the form
   my @fhs = cgi->upload('file_upload');  # this is what im talking about, this should get all the files. I also tried using trim_param() instead of cgi->upload.

}
```

Comment: Do you mean `$cgi` in `cgi->upload('file_upload')`?

Comment: nope, but it can mean that too.

Comment: your html is invalid (enctype/formid), your javascript is invalid(formid) , your perl is invalid (lowercase "cgi") -- validate your html ( validator.w3.org) , and copy/paste and beware of typos

Comment: What do you mean my html and javascript is invalid?

Comment: there isn't much I can mean. the enctype attribute is invalid, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form .  your form hasn't got an id, so `$('#myForm')` won't do anything -- you copied that from the ajaxform tutorial, but you didn't copy the html -- all these details matter

Comment: Did you make any progress? Still trying to solve this issue? If solved, please write as an answer and accept your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this..

[Can Perl's CGI.pm process Firefox's <input type="file", multiple=""> form fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448117/can-perls-cgi-pm-process-firefoxs-input-type-file-multiple-form-fields)

Fix it on the server side:

#### Not tested code just a hack/example

```
 my @fhs = upload('file_upload');
 use File::Type;
 my $ft = File::Type->new();
 my $i = 0;
 my %mimes = { ( $i++ => $ft->checktype_contents(<$_>)) } @fhs;
```

or something like that..

This helps too
http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#PROCESSING-A-FILE-UPLOAD-FIELD