# How to upload multiple files in perl?

Tags: perl, cgi, fastcgi, perl-module, mod-perl

I need to upload multiple files using perl cgi.
i used form type as

> enctype="multipart/form-data
>   and also set 
>    multiple='multiple' in input type file.

just need to know what should we do write at server side ?

Can anybody tell me how to upload multiple files using perl?

Comment: Are you asking how to include files in an HTTP request, or how to receive them in a CGI script?

Comment: The unedited post says 'need to know what should we do write at server side'

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448117/can-perls-cgi-pm-process-firefoxs-input-type-file-multiple-form-fields

Answer (score 3):

The following piece of code is enough and upload files present in the params to /storage location:

```
use CGI;
my $cgi = new CGI;
my @files = $cgi->param('multi_files[]');
my @io_handles=$cgi->upload('multi_files[]');
foreach my $upload(@files){
    print "Filename: $upload<br>";
    my $file_temp_path = "/storage";
    my $upload_file  = shift @io_handles; 
    open (UPLOADFILE,">$file_temp_path/$upload") or print "File Open Error";
    binmode UPLOADFILE;
    while (<$upload_file>) {
        print UPLOADFILE;
    }
}
print "Files Upload done";
```

Comment: Thank you, this saved me a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, you first retrive the file file handle like this:

```
 use CGI;
 my $q = CGI->new();
 my $myfh = $q->upload('field_name');
```

Now you have a filehandle to the temporary storage whither the file was uploaded.

The uploaded file anme can be had using the param() method.

```
 $filename = $q->param('field_name');
```

and the temporary file can be directly accessed via:

```
 $filename = $query->param('uploaded_file');
 $tmpfilename = $query->tmpFileName($filename);
```

I highly recommend giving the [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#PROCESSING-A-FILE-UPLOAD-FIELD) docs a good solid read, a couple of times.  While not trivial, it's all rather straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should handle multiple files upload:

```
my @fhs = $Cgi->upload('files');

foreach my $fh (@fhs) {
    if (defined $fh) {      
        my $type = $Cgi->uploadInfo($fh)->{'Content-Type'};
        next unless ($type eq "image/jpeg");

        my $io_handle = $fh->handle;
        open (OUTFILE,'>>','/var/directory/'.$fh);
        while (my $bytesread = $io_handle->read(my $buffer, 1024)) {
            print OUTFILE $buffer;
        }
        close (OUTFILE);
    }
}
```

Ofc 'files' is the name of the file upload form.